# How to write instrumented test for isolated stuff

Tags: android, android-testing

Firstly, apologies for the ridiculous title but I really could not come up with something more accurate.

I'm writing an app that interfaces with a particular type of network device. I can write instrumented tests that interact with said device just fine but those tests obviously only work if the device is accessible if the system running the tests are on the same network. Hence, using Firebase to run the tests is impossible because Firebase does not have access to the type of device the app interacts with.

However, it leads me back to a more generic question. How do you handle instrumented tests for functionality that is not publicly accessible? Be it special devices or networks, login credentials (hardcoding login credentials seem wrong), etc.

Is there any way to mock them? So say when you press a button you can mock a positive result?

Hope this made a sliver of sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can.

For example, mock framework - https://github.com/mockito/mockito

Comment: I am familiar with mockito but could you provide a simple example on how to mock the response when clicking a button?